# IOCTL locking kernel on Xeon E3-1270 v5

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

Has anyone experienced an issue with a system lock up when using IOWR with IOCTL on an Intel Xeon E3-1270 CPU? I have 3 different distributions (Centos 7.2, Ubuntu 14.04, Ubuntu 16.04) on 3 different Dell boxes using the above CPU and every time I use IOCTL with an IOWR the system locks up as soon as I access the memory sent up in the arg variable of the ioctl call.

Here's is an example code:

Kernel Module Header:

```
#include <linux/ioctl.h>

#define IOC_MAGIC 'k'

typedef struct
{
    int test1;
    int test2;
} bufferTest;

#define IOCTL_HELLO _IO(IOC_MAGIC,0)
#define IOCTL_BUFFER_TEST  _IOWR(IOC_MAGIC,1, bufferTest)
```

Kernel Module Source:

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/fs.h> // required for various structures related to files liked fops.
#include <linux/semaphore.h>
#include <linux/cdev.h>
#include "ioctl_basic.h"    //ioctl header file
#include <linux/version.h>
#include <asm/uaccess.h>

int open(struct inode *inode, struct file *filp)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Inside open \n");
    return 0;
}

int release(struct inode *inode, struct file *filp)
{
    printk (KERN_INFO "Inside close \n");
     return 0;
}

long ioctl_funcs(struct file *filp, unsigned int cmd, unsigned long arg)
{
    int ret=0;
    int index=0;
    bufferTest *bufferPtr = NULL;
    void *userPtr = NULL;

    printk(KERN_INFO "ioctl_func: %u\n", cmd);

    switch(cmd) {

    case IOCTL_HELLO:
        printk(KERN_INFO "Hello ioctl world\n");
        ret = 1;
        break;
    case IOCTL_BUFFER_TEST:
        bufferPtr = (bufferTest *)arg;
        userPtr = (void *)arg;

        if (access_ok(VERIFY_WRITE, userPtr, sizeof(bufferTest)))
        {
            printk(KERN_INFO "Success verify memory write\n");
            printk(KERN_INFO "test1: %d, test2: %d\n", bufferPtr->test1, bufferPtr->test2);
        }
        else
            printk(KERN_INFO "Failed to verify memory write\n");
        break;
    default:
        printk(KERN_INFO "Unknown command: %d\n", cmd);
        break;
     }

    return ret;
}

struct file_operations fops = {
 .open =   open,
 .unlocked_ioctl =  ioctl_funcs,
 .release = release
};


struct cdev *kernel_cdev;


int char_arr_init (void) {
    int ret;
    dev_t dev_no,dev;

    kernel_cdev = cdev_alloc();
    kernel_cdev->ops = &fops;
    kernel_cdev->owner = THIS_MODULE;
    printk (" Inside init module\n");
    ret = alloc_chrdev_region( &dev_no , 0, 1,"char_arr_dev");
    if (ret < 0) {
        printk("Major number allocation is failed\n");
    return ret;
    }

    Major = MAJOR(dev_no);
    dev = MKDEV(Major,0);

    printk (" The major number for your device is %d\n", Major);
    ret = cdev_add( kernel_cdev,dev,1);
    if(ret < 0 )
    {
        printk(KERN_INFO "Unable to allocate cdev");
        return ret;
    }

    return 0;
}

void char_arr_cleanup(void) {
    printk(KERN_INFO " Inside cleanup_module\n");
    cdev_del(kernel_cdev);
    unregister_chrdev_region(Major, 1);
}

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
module_init(char_arr_init);
module_exit(char_arr_cleanup);
```

Test Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "ioctl_basic.h"  //ioctl header file

main ( ) {
    int fd;
    bufferTest buffer;

    fd = open("/dev/temp", O_RDWR);

    if (fd == -1)
    {
        printf("Error in opening file \n");
        return;
    }

    ioctl(fd,IOCTL_HELLO);  //ioctl call

    buffer.test1 = 5;
    buffer.test2 = 10;

    printf("buffer ptr: %p, test1: %d, test2: %d\n", &buffer, buffer.test1, buffer.test2);

    ioctl(fd,IOCTL_BUFFER_TEST,&buffer);

    close(fd);
}
```

In the kernel module I cast (bufferTest *) to the arg parameter, as soon as I try to print "test1" or "test2" the system will lock up. This does not happen on any of my other systems not using this particular CPU.

If I use the copy_to_user and copy_from_user to copy the arg parameter to a local structure in the kernel module then things work fine, but I thought using the IOWR define I can access the memory directly. It seems like the Xeon E3-1270 processor is having some kind of issue, and I can't figure out what it is. Has anyone else experienced this issue?

Comment: I updated the question as you asked. Is this better?

Comment: Much better. I recommend adding the `[c]` tag as your programming language. Hopefully you'll get some readers with the correct skills to read your Q (not me ;-( ). Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

> If I use the copy_to_user and copy_from_user to copy the arg parameter to a local structure in the kernel module then things work fine, but I thought using the IOWR define I can access the memory directly.

No, irrespectively to the type of ioctl request you need to access user space memory in a common way. Aside from `copy_from_user` there is `__get_user` macro for read simple types from user space:

```
    if (access_ok(VERIFY_WRITE, userPtr, sizeof(bufferTest)))
    {
        int test1, test2;
        printk(KERN_INFO "Success verify memory write\n");
        __get_user(test1, &buffer->test1); // Read value of 'buffer->test1' into test1 
        __get_user(test2, &buffer->test2); // Read value of 'buffer->test2' into test2
        printk(KERN_INFO "test1: %d, test2: %d\n", test1, test2);
    }
```

---

Linux kernel doesn't aware of ioctl types and their meaning. Their usage is just a convention.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have kernel modules which use the IOWR definition which allows the kernel module to directly access the user space address with no problem. It's been running on dozens of systems for years with fairly recent and 5-6 year old CPUs. However, for some reason only this new Xeon E3-1270 v5 seems to lock up hard if I use the exact same method. It only works if I use the copy_from_user macro. I just don't understand why. Was I just lucky in the past or is there something new in the Xeon which is forcing this? Maybe a new MMU? It just seems odd.

Comment: `Was I just lucky in the past` - Exactly.